# Django Admin tables not displaying correctly

Tags: django, admin

[image: django admin incorrectly displaying tables?]

Has anyone seen this before? I've tried making new apps, projects, etc.

All thats in my admin.py file is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import UserProfile, Tribe, Membership

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Tribe)
admin.site.register(Membership)
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

I've not got any static files or css in the app..?

Comment: What is not displaying?

Comment: Unless you add `list_display` attribute to a `ModelAdmin` instance registered for your model, only the `__unicode__` or `__str__` property will be displayed in Django admin's list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that inherit `admin.ModelAdmin`, update the fields to be shown in the `list_display` tuple, and register `TribeAdmin` instead of `Tribe`. Do the same for the rest.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import UserProfile, Tribe, Membership

# Register your models here.

class TribeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_1', 'field_2',)

admin.site.register(Tribe, TribeAdmin)
# admin.site.register(Membership)
# admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

For all the available options, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) or an easy to understand beginner tutorial from the [DjangoBook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html) (please note its for an outdated Django Version, but fields works with Django 1.8)

With Django 1.8 you can use.

```
@admin.register(Tribe)
class TribeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field',)
```